# Reading from a Tuple and making a String in Scala

Tags: string, scala, tuples

I have a list of Tuple(s) like:

```
val rez = List((A, B, C, D, E, WrappedArray(F1, F2, F3)), (A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, WrappedArray(F4, F5)))
```

What I am trying to do is to create a string from each tuple in the list, so that (e.g., for the first tuple):

```
if(C == "Bob") then "A => (F1 \/ F2 \/ F3)"
```

The elements in the Tuple are, of course, of different types (in the `WrappedArray()` are of the same type).

My difficult part is how to make the string like `(F1 \/ F2 \/ F3)` from the elements within the `WrappedArray()`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the second element in the list has a WrappedArray of only two elements (F4, F5).. how should it be handled?

Comment: @rogue-one, it should become like `(F4 \/ F5)`, as the `WrappedArray` in my case has a different number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly.. the below should work..

```
val rez = List(("A", "B", "Bob", "D", "E", Array("F1", "F2", "F3")), ("A2", "B2", "Bob", "D2", "E2", Array("F4", "F5")))

val result = rez map {
 case (a, b, c, d, e, array) if(c == "Bob") => s"$a => ${array.mkString(" \\/ ")}"
}
result: List[String] = List(A => F1 \/ F2 \/ F3, A2 => F4 \/ F5)
```

Comment: "Yes, Sir!" It's really working. I tried so much, in different ways :(. Thank you so much!